# printing takes long time while consuming all CPU

Tags: windows-xp, printer, parallel-port

My HP 500 C printer is suddenly extrem slow. The last action was the Microsoft update at the weekend. No other software change at the system. Symptoms:

- Slow output of pages (3 minutes for one page)
- The process takes 100% CPU load during this time.

Do you have any suggestion what to check? Operating System is Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition, Service Pack 3, German edition.

Comment: Have 2 instances of this exact problem (print jobs were quick in Win2000 and now slow on XP machines). Both printers are good workhorses (large Oki 7530 colour laser and a Toshiba TEC B-SV4). Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: No, never solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options:

1. Rollback the driver update: [How To Use the Roll Back Driver Feature in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283657)
2. Use System Restore to rollback the computer to its state before the Windows Update (somewhat brutal)
3. Or better still: Download the driver from HP for the [HP Deskjet 500 Printer series for XP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=14599&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=25429&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=228).

Comment: The HP web page does not offer a driver for Windows XP. It just informs you that all the best is already distributed in Windows.

Comment: Did you have any luck with my other points?

Comment: Did not found that driver update that I could roll back.

Answer (score 0):

If windows update is to blame, go to http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/ (WARNING! Internet Explorer-only link!) and look for your printer. You may be able to find older driver for it and download it. Then you could hide the printer driver update so it won't be downloaded by windows update.

I've had similar problems with a Samsung printer and some drivers form windows update (~30 KiB file becomes 300 MiB print job, printing takes forever and similar) and fixed it by changing driver.