# XP LPT Print jobs slow to spool with high CPU usage previously quick on Win2K

Tags: windows-xp, printing

Have 2 instances of the exact problem mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/q/206373/102661).

Previous (old) machines were Windows 2000's (latest updates), AMD Durons 1ghtz with 1gb RAM.

Updates (reinstalled) machines are Windows XP 32bit (latest updates), AMD Sempron 2800 (2gb RAM) and a Intel core 2 6300 (1.5gb RAM).

The Sempron has an [Oki C7350](http://www.oki.co.uk/support/printer/printer-drivers/detail.aspx?prodid=tcm:122-2858&driverid=tcm:122-37564-16) attached to LPT1.

The core 2 has a [Toshiba TEC B-SV4](http://www.toshibatec-ris.com/products_overseas/printer/desktop_barcode_printer/b-sv4t/) attached to LPT1.

Have 2 instances of this exact problem (print jobs were quick in Win2000 and now slow on XP machines).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's article
[100 Percent CPU Usage Occurs When You Print on an LPT Printer Port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318273)
says :

> **SYMPTOMS**
>
> When you print on an LPT printer port, 100 percent CPU usage occurs
>   until the print job is completed. This slows down other programs until
>   the print job is completed. In some case, other programs may slow down
>   enough that they seem completely unresponsive. This behavior affects
>   all power users who have many programs running at one time.
>
> **CAUSE**
>
> This behavior occurs because Windows does not have interrupt support
>   for LPT printers.
>
> **WORKAROUND**
>
> To work around this behavior, print to a Universal Serial Bus (USB)
>   printer port. If the printer does not have this capability, use a
>   parallel-USB cable.

Comment: I don't have any slowdowns on the PC's in question, just a print job which takes an age to spool to the LPT port. 'Use a USB port' isn't really what I'd consider an accurate answer to 'why', even though it might fix the problem...! I'm afraid I can only try it with 1 of the printers.

Comment: I would suggest to try using usb with that one printer, before looking for another explanation.